# Is there any way to tell if I fought/seen a monster without having to check the Enemy Index?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

I would like to fill out my Enemy Index as much as possible just for the sake of knowing what monsters exist for Squad missions and the like. Is there any marker in the field for enemies you have encountered and or killed before? Similar to pokemon's little pokeball next to the name of Pokemon you have already caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no marker like this in the game. The only way to know if you've fought something is to look it up in the index.